# How to add to an array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I’m trying to add to an array in a loop but only the first element in the loop is added.

**The array**

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'john' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'adam' (length=13)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 3
      'name' => string 'mary' (length=11)
```

**My loop**

```
foreach ($loops as $key => $loop) {
    $idArray['id'] =  $loop['id'];
}
var_dump($idArray); die();
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: That is because you are overwritting the key. Also, an array can't have identical keys.

Comment: you are overwriting the same variable over and over and over again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite your old value by assigning the new value to the array. An array can't have identical keys.

Try this:

```
foreach ($loops as $key => $loop)
{             
    $idArray['id'][] =  $loop['id'];
}
var_dump($idArray); die();
```

So you add items to an array inside your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ordinal values of the `$idarray` to be the primary key values of what you are iterating over you can do this.

```
$loops = array(array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'john'), /* ... */);

foreach ($loops as $key => $loop)
{             
    $idArray[$loop['id']] =  $loop;
}
var_dump($idArray); die();
```

`var_dump` will reveal this structure

```
array (size=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'john' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 2
      'name' => string 'adam' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 3
      'name' => string 'mary' (length=4)
```